# element has implicitly has any type angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

First of all I am displaying one popup and in that I have displayed two drop down dependent. Then user will upload file and click on submit button to save data.

So then I am calling API and getting error for second argument, below is fully details and code.

I have this array :

```
DocTypes: Array<any> = [
    {
      name: 'n1',
      attributes: ['a1'],
    },
    {
      name: 'n2',
      attributes: ['a2'],
    },
  ];
```

Now using this Array I am displaying dependent drop down as per below screenshot. In that when we select n1 then in second drop down it will display a1 and for n2 it will display a2. to achieve that I have done using below code.

[image]

```
<div class="fileTypesSelector">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="textbox">
          <mat-label>Select Type</mat-label>
          <mat-select
            [(ngModel)]="selectedType"
            (valueChange)="changeType($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let type of DoctTypes" [value]="type">{{
              type.name
            }}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div class="fileTypesSelector">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="textbox">
          <mat-label>Select Attribute</mat-label>
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedAttribute"
            panelClass="customQuarterDropdown">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let attribute of attributes" [value]="attribute">{{
                attribute
            }}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

ts file

```
selectedType = '';
selectedAttribute: string = '';
attributes: Array<any> = [];

  changeType(filetype: any) {
    this.attributes = filetype.attributes;
  }
```

Now user will select this both values and then select file and then click on submit button at that time I am calling below function to call API. But I am getting below error on that.

```
public uploadFile(): void {
this.apiService.uploadFile(this.uploadedFile, **this.selectedFileType['name'],** // for this argument error is coming
     this.companyid, this.selectedFileAttribute)
```

below is error coming for second argument.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
}
```

Comment: Stop using `any` for a start. Avoid using it as much as possible, is bad practice, define your own data types. If you hover over `(valueChange)="changeType($event)"` what does your IDE tells you what type is `$event`?

Answer (score 0):

I think ***this.attributes*** is not getting any value as it's an array so add any value you can use array.push method or spread operator too. viz. **this.attributes.push(filetype.attributes)**

Then use it as iterable for you ngFor & in template file use ***ngFor="let attribute of attributes[0]"**

Please let me know how it worked for you.